# Suddenly timeout when connecting via SSL/Https with some browsers

Tags: apache, firefox, ssl, https

The https-version of my website suddenly is not reachable any more from Firefox or Chrome (chrome shows ERR_TIMED_OUT). Both browsers behave as if the site was down. With Internet Explorer is working all right.

This happens on multiple computers since yesterday. I use a startcom.org signed certificate.

Wireshark shows:

```
TLSV1 Client Hello
TLSV1 Server Hello
Certificate
Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
Client Key Exchange, Change cipher spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
Encrypted Handshake Message, Change cipher spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
Encrypted Alert
TCP RST, ACK
```

A bit later there is a request from User-Agent: Microsoft-CryptoAPI/6.1 to crl.startssl.com/crt1-crl.crl

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by different behaviour when checking for certificate revocation (via CRLs) doesn't work. It seems that StartSSL has had some problems recently, and `http://crl.startssl.com/crt1-crl.crl` is quite slow to respond.

You can check whether it's enabled in your browser.

In IE: Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security -> Check for server certificate revocation

In Firefox, in `about:config` -> see the options that contain the text `crl` (and `ocsp`).

Comment: Tried setting Firefox config `services.sync.prefs.sync.security.OCSP.require` to false, did not change. Did not find a setting containing CRL.

Comment: The problem does not occur any more, the crl URL is accessible again.